# Checking if the SQL query returns null

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a problem. I am getting the sum of a certain column from the database. 
However, in some cases the sum should be 0 -> if there are no records that meet the criteria

In the view I have:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Sum, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

In ViewModel I have:

```
public override void save()
{
    Sum = new Sum(ATMAEntites).Calculate(IdEvent, IdDealer, "Standing");      
}
```

In the model class I have:

```
public int? Calculate(int IdEvent, int IdDealer, string CategoryName)
{
    return (from wydaneSprzedawcy in ATMAEntites.WydaneSprzedawcy
            where wydaneSprzedawcy.Bilety.IdEvent == IdEvent &&
                  wydaneSprzedawcy.IdDealer == IdDealer &&
                  wydaneSprzedawcy.Bilety.CategoryName == CategoryName
            select wydaneSprzedawcy.quantity).Sum();
}
```

I want check in the model whether the query returns null

Comment: your code will gives you ``0`` if no record match the ``where`` expression, but if ``ATMAEntites.WydaneSprzedawcy`` gives you sometimes ``null`` value, add test before enter in the loop like : ``return ATMAEntites.WydaneSprzedawcy == null ? 0 : (....)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that wydaneSprzedawcy.quantity is int and not nullable. Then you can try adding a cast to (int?) in the select, like this:

```
public int? Calculate(int IdEvent, int IdDealer, string CategoryName)
{
    return
        (
            from wydaneSprzedawcy in ATMAEntites.WydaneSprzedawcy
            where
                wydaneSprzedawcy.Bilety.IdEvent == IdEvent &&
                wydaneSprzedawcy.IdDealer == IdDealer &&
                wydaneSprzedawcy.Bilety.CategoryName == CategoryName
            select (int?)wydaneSprzedawcy.quantity
        ).Sum();
}
```

Now, if the query returns no records, sum should return null.